# Fast built-in command to get the last modified date of a file in Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, date-modified

I'm trying to get the last modified date of a bunch of files on Windows. On GNU systems, I can just use something like `stat -c %Y`.

I know about the `wmic` command, but the problem with that is that it is very slow. On my system, running the command `wmic datafile where Name="..." get LastModified /value` is around 4 to 7 times slower than using a port of GNU stat in an MSYS2 shell.

For my purposes, I need an alternative that is faster and built-in to either Windows itself, or the Visual Studio development tools. I don't really care about the output format because I can parse it manually myself.

Does anyone know if something like that exists?

Comment: You can almost certainly find a Windows port of `stat` (search for `"stat.exe"`). If not, it's only a few lines of C to write.

Comment: @AFH The problem is that I need a solution that is built in to either Windows or the VS dev tools. I've searched, but wmic is the only thing I've found.

Comment: If you've got VS, write the program yourself (call `stat()` or `lstat()`, depending on how you want symbolic links handled). Or it's probably straightforward in PowerShell, but I've never used that more than minimally.

Comment: When I say "built in" I mean that I need something that is already available. Of course I could write my own, but for what I am doing that isn't an appropriate solution. I'm writing a script that I need to deploy on a bunch of Windows PCs with VS dev tools installed at minimum. Bundling an executable program, or worse, source code that needs to be built, isn't going to work for my particular situation.

Powershell was something I hadn't thought of before, so I did just try that. Unfortunately, it is actually *much* slower than the wmic command.

Comment: Unless it is difficult in the context of local security or anti-virus policies, I can't see why you shouldn't distribute an executable with your script. If the PCs are on Windows 10, the Linux on Windows subsystem will already `stat`. You can invoke it with `bash -c`, though you will need to use the Linux, not the Windows file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Window command-line DIR should do the job, if you can parse the output by field. Pipe the output to a file as needed.

For example, **dir /o:d /t:w** orders files by date [/o:d] using the last time written i.e. modified) field [/t:w] and produces the following:

> Directory of C:\Intel\Logs
>
> 07/06/2016  10:28 PM              ..
>
> 07/06/2016  10:28 PM                 0 IntelCPHS.log
>
> 05/13/2017  10:01 PM           767,814 IntelGFX.log
>
> 10/17/2017  10:54 PM            51,608 IntelGFXCoin.log

[If you need time to the second](https://www.windows-commandline.com/get-file-modified-date-time/), try:

> forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @file @ftime"

Enter **dir /?** to see options for viewing files of certain attributes, output format etc.

Comment: Excellent - I didn't know about `@...` options in `ForFiles`. It's a pity that you need to schedule a new copy of `cmd` just to do an echo. In Linux `echo` and several other internal commands also have external binaries to avoid this, but I don't know of a standard Windows command which will do the equivalent.